# Extend dplyr's variable selection functionality to custom functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to use dplyr's variable selection functions in my own custom functions.  By dplyr's variable selection functions, I mean these:  https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-utils.R

Or, if you're familiar with dplyr, things like "contains", "one_of", "starts_with", etc.

What I'd like to be able to do is write a function that only operates on certain variables:

```
# note: pseudo code
foo = function(df, vars){
  for (var in vars){
     df$var = as.character(df$var)
  }
}
```

I'm aware of dplyr's "mutate_each" function, which allows me to do this, but I have to write a function that operates on a vector instead of writing a function that operates on a data.frame.

The purpose of my question is to be able to more cleanly add a custom function to a data processing pipeline.  For example, I want to ultimately do this:

```
df %>%
  foo(starts_with("varname"))
```

Rather than

```
df %>%
  mutate_each(funs(foo), starts_with("varname"))
```

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it means that you would need to write a customized function for each function you want to use in that way.. one for `sum`, one for `mean`, one for.. etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: Correct -- each function would do one thing

Comment: And do you want the result of `df %>% foo(starts_with("varname"))` to be exactly identical to the result of `df %>% mutate_each(funs(foo), starts_with("varname"))` (meaning it would result in a data.frame)?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the return object to be a data.frame

Comment: Part of what is so great about **dplyr** is that it standardizes how we expression data transformation processes. This makes for explicit, readable, although occasionally more verbose code. The `mutate_each` approach is perfectly clear about what it's doing. Your desired replacement is not.

Comment: You question is confusing because your pseudo code foo function takes two variables as input but then you use it with one variable as input in the next code block.

Comment: pseudo code wasn't well written, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
df %>%
  foo(starts_with("varname"))
```

It can be solved with

```
df %>% select(starts_with("varname")) %>% foo
```

If you really want one single function:

```
select_and_foo <- function(df,varname) {
    df %>% select(starts_with(varname)) %>% foo %>% return
}
```

Then

```
df %>% select_and_foo("varname")
```

### Example

```
# create sample data
set.seed(16)
sampledf <- matrix(rnorm(50), ncol = 10) %>% as.data.frame() %>% set_names(paste0(c(rep("H",5),rep("O",5)),1:10))

> sampledf
          H1          H2         H3         H4         H5        O6          O7         O8         O9         O10
1  0.4764134 -0.46841204  1.8471821 -1.6630805 -1.6477976 1.5274670 -0.67252558  0.2805551 -1.3253531  0.28390672
2 -0.1253800 -1.00595059  0.1119334  0.5759095 -0.3141739 1.0541781  0.13259853  0.5447834  2.0651357  0.12157699
3  1.0962162  0.06356268 -0.7460373  0.4727601 -0.1826816 1.0300710 -0.07092735  0.1308698  0.2421730  0.56634411
4 -1.4442290  1.02497260  1.6582137 -0.5427317  1.4704785 0.8401609 -0.94269547  0.2818444 -0.3490972  0.56903290
5  1.1478293  0.57314202  0.7217206  1.1276871 -0.8658988 0.2169647 -1.02203100 -0.2927308 -0.6308124 -0.09058676


# define a function that operates on dataframes and returns a dataframe
foo = . %>% solve %>% t %>% as.data.frame

# et voila
> sampledf %>% select(starts_with("H")) %>% foo
          H1         H2        H3          H4          H5
1  0.3004043 -0.2011219 0.2233852 -0.28712106  0.07735365
2  0.3557121 -0.9996712 0.4830006  0.30975840  0.61582865
3  1.7020360 -0.8657610 0.4686327 -0.35050079  1.61728993
4  0.4993172 -0.2886113 0.4811486 -0.04590702  0.81210612
5 -0.2118682  0.4379735 0.1178755  0.42998574 -0.48759158
```

Comment: Thanks nelson, much appreciated

Comment: Note that `df %>% select(starts_with("varname")) %>% foo` is not necessarily the same as `df %>% mutate_each(funs(foo), starts_with("varname"))` because when using `mutate_each` with one of the special `select` functions (like `starts_with`), columns that are not selected will be kept in the output (only the function `foo` will not be applied to them) while with `df %>% select(starts_with("varname")) %>% foo` only the selected columns will be returned.

Comment: I assume if I wanted to do the mutate version of this, I'd need to split off a temporary data.frame, perform whatever needs performing, and then add it back to the original data.frame to return

Comment: Exactly. Of course, you could also wrap that into a function, call it select_split_foo_combine or something. A simple cbind should suffice, just don't change the dimensions of the dataframe!